# nuxti18n dynamicRouteParams

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, blogs, dynamic-routing, nuxt-i18n

I'm creating a blog.
I created a dynamic page [blog] .vue.
At this point for each page I fetch the data with `useAsyncData`.
So far everything is ok.

However, I need that each article be associated with its corresponding language (with translated url).
**Here is the problem.**

At this point on the `nuxt.config.ts` I set

```js
i18n: {
 dynamicRouteParams: true,
},
```

Ok, now as documentation (https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/options/routing#dynamicrouteparams) inside [body].vue I have set

```js
definePageMeta({
  nuxtI18n: {
    en: { id: 'my-post' },
    fr: { id: 'mon-article' }
  }
})
```

The problem is that `definePageMeta` is a **compiler macro** therefore, the page meta object cannot reference the component (or values defined on the component).
(https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages/#page-metadata)

This means that i cant change **dinamically nuxtI18n** object like this

```js
const data= await useAsyncData(...)

definePageMeta({
  nuxtI18n: {
    en: { 
      blog: data.alternate_languages.en.url
    },
    fr: { 
      blog: data.alternate_languages.fr.url
    }
  }
})
```

At this point `dynamicRouteParams:true` is useless and i have no way to translate an article

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution I used to solve this problem is to pass directly to `route.meta` like this:

```
route.meta.nuxtI18n = slugs
```

Unfortunately it's impossible to change dynamically `definePageMeta` values.

For reference, this specific topic is discussed in this issue: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/i18n/issues/1736